# OTG is not detecting in VIVO Y30

Tags: usb-on-the-go, vivo

I have SanDisk MicroSD OTG and MiVi MicroSD to C-Type converter. I am trying to mount OTG in my VIVO Y30 but it is not detecting. I checked in Settings > Ram and Storage space, but OTG is disabled. I also installed OTG checker app, but no luck. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: [Open Settings-> Additional Settings-> OTG connection. Here you need to enable the option](https://www.91mobiles.com/questions/does-vivo-y19-support-otg)

Comment: Cannot see Additional Settings option in Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VIVO Y30 mobile, pls go to setting and search for OTG and enable this (by default, it is off) .. Once making this, you have to connect any usb device within 5 mins or the setting will be on off automatically. Please try and let us know

Comment: Yes. I had to search first.